# Interest use Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am from remote place of Nepal. I am very interesting to use Ubuntu I have low speed of internet. I was try many time to download Ubuntu but I have no download. Can I have CD or DVD from where?

Comment: You can also try to use a **download manager**.  It can resume/continue the download when it was cancelled.

Comment: The cheapest and easiest method would be  borrowing ubuntu cd/dvd/live usb from a friend or a computer enthusiast.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading through torrent. It will take time depending on your internet connection, but it will not corrupt your download.

Also, a Ubuntu CD will only contain very basic packages. To use Sound,videos etc. You still need an internet connection to get those packages and make these basic functionality work.

Answer (score 0):

At the very bottom, you can change the type of currency. It only allows me US dollars, Euro, and Pounds. Good luck!

http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1146

Comment: Where is Ubuntu shop

Comment: Cononical is the company that owns Ubuntu, so it is the official website. I sent you the link to the Ubuntu Desktop version

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a DVD from the [Ubuntu shop](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).

The DVDs are only available in 64 bit version.

If you require 32 bit you will need to [download a distribution or make your own CD/DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)

Answer (score 0):

The last I checked, AMAZON was selling Ubuntu on a rather slow but bootable usb memory stick.  I'm not saying that's your ideal solution, nor will it be your least expensive, but it is yet another option for you to consider.  I'll see if I can find the link...

Oh wow how convenient.  Amazon sells a special edition dvd containing both the 64 and 32 bit versions for about $11 and free shipping.
[http://www.amazon.com/Ubuntu-Linux-14-04-Special-DVD/dp/B00JRSOCNM/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1432028448&sr=8-2&keywords=ubuntu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JRSOCNM)

At twice that price, $22 and possibly free shipping, they offer it on the usb flash drive I mentioned first.
[http://www.amazon.com/Ubuntu-Linux-14-04-Trusty-Bootable/dp/B00JXNOMV8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1432028560&sr=8-1&keywords=ubuntu+flash](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JXNOMV8)